# How can I adjust the label width whenever I change the monitor

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using this code to develop a layout using Tkinter. I am using a screen of resolution 1600 x 900. But I want to use this same layout in different monitors also. But the layout gets smaller or bigger according to the screen size. I want to update the layout dynamically with the screen change.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1600x900+0+0") 

Label(root,text='xyz', background='blue', foreground='cyan', font=("Times New Roman",60),borderwidth=4,width=7,height=1,relief='raised').grid(row=0,column=0)
Label(root,text='abc', background='blue', foreground='cyan', font=("Times New Roman",60),borderwidth=4,width=17,relief='raised').grid(row=0,column=1)
Label(root,text='pqr', background='blue', foreground='cyan', font=("Times New Roman",60),borderwidth=4,width=5,relief='raised').grid(row=0,column=2)
Label(root,text='stu', background='blue', foreground='cyan', font=("Times New Roman",60),borderwidth=4,width=3,relief='raised').grid(row=0,column=3)
Label(root,text='i', background='blue', foreground='cyan', font=("Times New Roman",60),borderwidth=4,width=3,relief='raised').grid(row=0,column=4)
```

Comment: calculate the proportional change (scale) to your base resolution and multiply the sizes by it

Comment: The simplest solution is to _not_ change the window size. Instead, just let the window be it's natural size. Is there a reason why you want to manually adjust the layout for different sizes? Are you certain that's a problem you need to solve?